# Is it possible to only use CSS to hide/show events in Salesforce B2C Commerce Cloud

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-commerce-cloud, salesforce-developer

I am a Salesforce Commerce Cloud practitioner. Here I am trying to create a anchor tag which when clicked hide/show certain part of the page.

For example:-
If we want to show/hide the **enter promo code** element with a hyper-link in the cart section.

[image]
[image]

I would appreciate any someone can provide the solution or any material for reference.

**Dated:-19-10-2022**
I tried to achieve to goal firstly by using javascript. I which i am getting problem. I am able to make a click me button but i think there is some problem with the connection between button and js script.

Code:-
[image]

Screen View:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular thing to do that. You can do it with standard Javascript.

Also, SFRA uses bootstrap 4 and you can do it with Bootstrap Collapse.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: I am considered your advice and tried to implement it in javascript first. I managed to create a logic for hiding the element but it is not working.

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
                <isscript>
                function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-5 col-md-4 totals");
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                   x.style.display = "none";
                }
                }
                </isscript>`

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel.I have had some progress on the topic. I would be a great help if you help mitigate some problems.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause by the code js is not correct. Please try again with the code below:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-5 col-md-4 totals");
if (x[0].style.display === "none") {
    x[0].style.display = "block";
} else {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
}
}
```